# Python plot real time data

Tags: python, qt, plot, telnet

I have a Python script that establishes a telnet connection to a power supply and collects output voltage data. I will be collecting the data at a rate of 1 Hz. The script is similar to the following snippet with alot of irrelevant code left out.

```
root = tk.Tk()

# Connect to Device
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST,PORT)

# Turn On
tn.write("OUT 1\r")

def get_voltage():
    # Get Current Voltage
    current_voltage = tn.write("MV?\r")

    # get the voltage again in one millisecond
    root.after(1, get_voltage)
...
get_voltage()
root.mainloop()
```

What I'd like to do is plot the `current_voltage` as it is received. I don't have numpy or matplotlib installed on my machine and it will be difficult to do so due to not having admin. rights. However I do have Qwtplot and Qwt libraries installed. Can anyone please recommend the best way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: You may be able to install `matplotlib ` via pip's `--user` option. Just try `pip install matplotlib --user`, and it will install to your home directory.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I was able to get pylab installed. Do you have any suggested approaches?

Comment: What do you mean by approach? You've got a plotting library, plot your data. You provide no information about what your data is like, it's not feasible to say how to plot it properly.